# jQuery click() to update list with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a list of items editable and update with AJAX using jQuery.

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li data-id="1">
       <span class="title">Title 1</span><span><a href="#" class="changeLink">Change</a></span>
   </li>
   <li data-id="2">
       <span class="title">Title 2</span><span><a href="#" class="changeLink">Change</a></span>
   </li>
   <li data-id="3">
       <span class="title">Title 3</span><span><a href="#" class="changeLink">Change</a></span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('a.changeLink').on('click', function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // get parent LI element
    var li = $(this).closest('li'); 
    // catch current title
    var title = li.children('span.title').text(); 
    // replace span
    li.children('span.title').html('<input type="text" value="'+title+'" />');
    // change the link class and label 
    $(this).removeClass('changeLink').addClass('saveLink').text('Save'); 
});

$('a.saveLink').on('click', function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // get parent LI element
    var li = $(this).closest('li'); 
    // get the id for the AJAX query
    var id = li.attr('data-id'); 
    // get the input value
    var title = li.children('span.title input').val(); 
    // restore span text with new
    li.children('span.title').text(title); 
    // restore link
    $(this).removeClass('saveLink').addClass('changeLink').text('Change'); 
    // make AJAX post to save new title
    $.post('updatetitle.php',{ 'id': id, 'title': title }, function(){ alert('OK'); }); 
});
```

My problem seem to be that the saveLink click event never occurs. Also the changeLink click event seem to happen more than once. Why does this happen - the link don't have the `changeLink` class anymore?

I put this in a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtheman/SZk4h/1/

Glad if I can get some input, what is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The event will be associated to an element and not specifically to a class**..

If you want to work it with class you might need to **delegate** the event

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$('ul#list').on('click', 'a.changeLink , a.saveLink', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('changeLink')) {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        var title = li.children('span.title').text();
        li.children('span.title')
            .html('<input type="text" value="' + title + '" />');
        $(this).removeClass('changeLink')
               .addClass('saveLink').text('Save');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('saveLink')) {
        var li = $(this).closest('li');
        var id = li.attr('data-id');
        var title = li.children('span.title').find('input').val();
        li.children('span.title').text(title);
        $(this).removeClass('saveLink')
               .addClass('changeLink').text('Change');
        //$.post('updatetitle.php',
        // { 'id': id, 'title': title }, function(){ alert('OK'); });
    }
});​
```

Your problem was this line

```
var title = li.children('span.title input').val();
```

`.children()` will only get the immediate children of the element.

Replace it with

```
var title = li.children('span.title').find('input').val();
```

**[Check Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/SZk4h/16/)**

Comment: Great, this solves my first issue. But why does the changeLink event fire more than once clicking on the link? See this: http://jsfiddle.net/jtheman/SZk4h/10/

Comment: Also title = li.children('span.title input').val(); returns undefined - why?

Answer (score 1):

use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. This is because

> $('a.saveLink').on('click', function(e)) //in this moment not elements exists,
>
> the .addClass('saveLink') // execute after

Comment: @jtheman You are correct, it should be `$(document).on('click', 'a.saveLink', function(e) {})`

Comment: live() is not deprecate, but use live() is more expensive

Answer (score 1):

`.saveLink` does not exist in the DOM the first time you bind the event.  One possible solution is to bind it once the `.saveLink` class is added.  Another is to use delegation.  Ideally, the `ul` would have an `id` attribute (otherwise you will have to use another parent up to `document`:

```
$("#ul-id").on('click', '.saveLink', function () { ...
```

Additionally, the `.changeLink` callback is never unbound from the links it is bound to originally.  This can be solved using delegation in the same way, or you can unbind the event in the callback.